# how to return a value given a set of conditions across 3 tables?

Tags: sql-server-2008, case, return-value

I am trying to have the data table return a the latest value given certain conditions and a null if they are note met.

I want to know the last time a patient was contacted.  This is identified with the progress note subject is 'Patient Contact'. So when looking at the data table that pulls from the following tables, how should it be coded to show the date?

### Patient Table

- MRN
- Name
- Phone

### Progress Notes Table

- Primary Key
- MRN
- Name
- Subject
- Date
- Body

### Ordered Therapy

- MRN
- Name
- Therapy

### *So That The results are*

Name ---- MRN --- Therapy - Last Pt. Contact

J.Doe  ----   123-----     Pump -----          2/10/14

A.Smith --  342-----     Dressing

D.Rix   -----  984    ---- Surface     --  9/6/14

Comment: Google "SQL Aggregate Function Tutorial"

Answer (score 0):

use `LEFT JOIN` to get all patients and NULL value if no progress notes record found and `GROUP BY` to get last patient contact date.

```
SELECT P.Name, P.MRN , MAX(Therapy) as Therapy, MAX([Date]) as [Last Pt. Contact]
FROM Patient P
LEFT JOIN ProgressNotes PN
ON P.MRN = PN.MRN
LEFT JOIN OrderedTherapy O
ON O.MRN = P.MRN
GROUP BY P.Name, P.MRN
```